# How to write a dynamic html tag

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have this `for-in` loop that is supposed to return a `div` element with an `img` tag that has an onclick function. For some reason I get this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - I have no idea where I missed it. Any help or advice will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
for (var key in icons) {

 var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
 //the variables below points to objects
 var type = icons[key];
 var name_place = type.name;
 var icon = type.icon;
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = '<img'  + ' src="' + icon + '"' +     
 'onclick="displayMarker( ' + name_place + ' )"' + '> ' + name_place;
  legend.appendChild(div);
}

 //When I try: 
 div.innerHTML = '<img'  + ' src="' + icon + '"' + 
 'onclick="displayMarker(name_place)"> ' + name_place;
```

the variable `name_place` is not passed into the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var icons = {
  one: {
    name: 'name1',
    icon: 'icon1.img'
  },
  two: {
    name: 'name2',
    icon: 'icon2.img'
  }
};

function displayMarker( arg) {
  console.log("displayMarker argument %s value: %s", typeof arg, arg);
}

for (var key in icons) {

  var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
  //the variables below points to objects
  var type = icons[key];
  var name_place = type.name;
  var icon = type.icon;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '" onclick="displayMarker(\'' + name_place + '\')"> ' + name_place;
  legend.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="legend"></div>
```

You need to put add the quotation marks for the parameter for the function parameter.

Since you are already using the single quote for string representation, you need to escape `\'` the characters for parameter passing.

Suggestion: Use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) if possible.